# handling fragment after manually phone lock in View pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

Actually, i am implementing a TabLayout, so in main MainActivity, I load the TabFragment and in the tabFragment(contain two `fragments`) I used the ViewPager.

So the problem is when I am on fragment two in TabLayout and the after the screen goes off it will move to the **Fragment one**(**Default one**). So how can I tackle this one

Here is TabFragment Code:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {


    public TabFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 2 ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View x=inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main_menu,null);
        tabLayout=(TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager =(ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        //viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });
    return x;
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(), "Fragment One");
        adapter.addFragment(new Offers(), "fragment Two");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }
        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: What do yo mean by "after the screen goes off"?

Comment: @techDigi can you please post your main activity onResume() code.

Comment: i simply override onResume() method and call super

Comment: Try getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager()

Comment: @AndyDeveloper  i tried but stil same problem

Comment: @techDigi okey then try with getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() can't resolve method

Comment: @santalu it means ehen i manually lock the phone

Answer (score -1):

Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`. read documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html). `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` only stores the `savedInstanceState` of fragments, and destroys all the fragments when they lose focus.

Comment: still same problem

Comment: are you using getChildFragmentManager() for sure ? try with getFragmentManager()

Comment: Why you reject my changes, first check your link that is not working so i made changes in that link @droidev